# the driver executable does not exist: c:\demo\drivers\edgedriver-windows-64bit

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Environment: Win 10, Edge 25.10586.0.0

I am using [`WebDriver Extensions`](https://github.com/webdriverextensions/webdriverextensions) and trying to do cross-browser testing with Edge and others. All the WebDriver executables are under `C:\demo\drivers`,  including `edgedriver-windows-64bit`, `chromedriver-windows-32bit`. whenever I do `clean and build`, then test, `Netbeans` always says :

> The driver executable does not exist: @Edge C:\demo\drivers\edgedriver-windows-64bit
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException
>       at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:121)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:116)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriverService.access$000(EdgeDriverService.java:33)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(EdgeDriverService.java:63)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriverService.createDefaultService(EdgeDriverService.java:55)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.(EdgeDriver.java:120)
>       at com.github.webdriverextensions.junitrunner.WebDriverRunner$BrowserConfiguration.createDriver(WebDriverRunner.java:488)
>       at com.github.webdriverextensions.junitrunner.WebDriverRunner$BrowserConfiguration.access$400(WebDriverRunner.java:372)
>       at com.github.webdriverextensions.junitrunner.WebDriverRunner.runChild(WebDriverRunner.java:200)
>       at com.github.webdriverextensions.junitrunner.WebDriverRunner.runChild(WebDriverRunner.java:57)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)

in `pom` :

```
<groupId>com.github.webdriverextensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdriverextensions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-drivers</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <drivers>
                    <driver>
                        <name>chromedriver</name>
                        <version>2.22</version>
                    </driver>
                    <driver>
                        <name>edgedriver</name>
                        <platform>windows</platform>
                        <bit>64</bit>
                        <version>3.14366</version>
                    </driver>
                    <driver>
                        <name>internetexplorerdriver</name>
                        <platform>windows</platform>
                        <bit>64</bit>
                        <version>2.53</version>
                    </driver>                        
                </drivers>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: Could you share your code as well??